# onDragEnd & onDrag values seem off in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, electron

I have the following functions:

```
_onDrag(e) {
    console.log("On Drag: "+e.clientY);

  }

  _onDragStart(e) {
    console.log("Drag Start: "+e.clientY);

  }

  _onDragEnd(e) {
    console.log("Drag End: "+e.clientY);
  }
```

I apply them to a React component I named `Canvas`:

```
   <Canvas 
          onDrag={this._onDrag.bind(this)}
          onDragStart={this._onDragStart.bind(this)}
          onDragEnd={this._onDragEnd.bind(this)}
   />
```

and in `Canvas` I just put them onto a normal HTML canvas:

```
    <canvas 
    ref="canvas" 
    draggable="true"

    onDrag={this.props.onDrag}
    onDragStart={this.props.onDragStart}
    onDragEnd={this.props.onDragEnd}
    />
```

However, when I drag drop on my canvas, my functions give me the following output:

> Drag Start: 600 2index_bundle.js:26414 On Drag: 486
>   40index_bundle.js:26414 On Drag: 483 4index_bundle.js:26414 On Drag:
>   482 4index_bundle.js:26414 On Drag: 479 4index_bundle.js:26414 On
>   Drag: 473 4index_bundle.js:26414 On Drag: 467 4index_bundle.js:26414
>   On Drag: 461 4index_bundle.js:26414 On Drag: 453
>   4index_bundle.js:26414 On Drag: 448 4index_bundle.js:26414 On Drag:
>   443 2index_bundle.js:26414 On Drag: 437 4index_bundle.js:26414 On
>   Drag: 433 4index_bundle.js:26414 On Drag: 430 4index_bundle.js:26414
>   On Drag: 427 2index_bundle.js:26414 On Drag: 424
>   4index_bundle.js:26414 On Drag: 420 2index_bundle.js:26414 On Drag:
>   417 4index_bundle.js:26414 On Drag: 413 2index_bundle.js:26414 On
>   Drag: 410 4index_bundle.js:26414 On Drag: 407 2index_bundle.js:26414
>   On Drag: 403 2index_bundle.js:26414 On Drag: 399
>   4index_bundle.js:26414 On Drag: 394 2index_bundle.js:26414 On Drag:
>   390 2index_bundle.js:26414 On Drag: 386 2index_bundle.js:26414 On
>   Drag: 381 4index_bundle.js:26414 On Drag: 378 2index_bundle.js:26414
>   On Drag: 374 2index_bundle.js:26414 On Drag: 369
>   2index_bundle.js:26414 On Drag: 366 4index_bundle.js:26414 On Drag:
>   364 2index_bundle.js:26414 On Drag: 359 4index_bundle.js:26414 On
>   Drag: 356 6index_bundle.js:26414 On Drag: 353 6index_bundle.js:26414
>   On Drag: 351 6index_bundle.js:26414 On Drag: 350
>   6index_bundle.js:26414 On Drag: 348 6index_bundle.js:26414 On Drag:
>   347 29index_bundle.js:26414 On Drag: 346 index_bundle.js:26414 On
>   Drag: 0 index_bundle.js:26424 Drag End: 1168

1. I don't understand why at `onDragEnd` the value is super far off (1168!!) 
   relatedly, its also interesting that at `onDragStart` the value is `600`, whereas then once I drag, it jumps to `479`.
2. I don't understand why at the end of `onDrag`, the value is being set to `0`

Can anyone explain this to me?